# Is it possible to loop through each row of a table in a database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops

I'm trying to loop through each row of a table in a database, then once I'm on a particular row get the value of a certain column. Is this possible? I've done a couple Google searches but nothing really concrete. I try using the mysqli_fetch_array() function but when I do I get the results of a column. I want to target each row. The code I have so far gets me the "nid" column. That's not what I want. I want to iterate through each row.

```
<?php

    $serverName = "localhost";
    $username = "user1";
    $password = "sp@99#1";
    $databaseName = "developer_site";

    // Connection
    $connection = new mysqli($serverName, $username, $password, $databaseName);

    // Check Connection
    if ($connection->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed:" . $connection->connect_error);
    } // line ends if statement

    $queryNodeRevision = "SELECT nid FROM node_revision";
    // line above creates variable $queryNodeRevision > selects column "nid" from table "node_revision"

    $results = mysqli_query($connection, $queryNodeRevision) or die("Bad Query: $results");

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
          echo "NID: ";
          echo $row['nid'];
          echo "<br/>";
    } 
  ?>
```

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and ideally should not be used in new code.

Comment: Remember, [the `mysqli` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) is full of examples.

Comment: I think you need to look at the SQL manual and specifically at the WHERE clause. It is not normal to run through a database table like it was a sequential file.... because they are not

Comment: Also checkout the SELECT while you are in there! You can select more than one column at a time i.e. `SELECT nid,nad,nod FROM node_revision WHERE nad = 'somevalue'` then you only get the rows you actually want to see and the columns you want to know about

Comment: You are using the wrong tool for the task you're trying to accomplish. Any SQL engine can give you the records you want if you ask it correctly. External code shouldn't be used to filter a query's results when the query itself can do it much more efficiently.

Comment: @Shawn Right tool ... just not using it properly :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly I wouldn't say that PHP is the right tool, no matter how it's used, to query information from a database. Code shouldn't try to force an outcome that a query can do natively.

Comment: @Shawn By right tool I ment a database

Comment: @RiggsFolly Gotcha. It took me a while to appreciate that databases are more than just a place to store data. :-)

Comment: Just want to point out that `$row` is your row. Your row contains columns with values. What you do with it is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can select rows by a certain condition with an SQL query alone and also select all columns.
`SELECT * FROM node_revision where condition;`

`condition` could be anything. For example another_row = 'something'.

But if, for some reason, you need to process the `nid` inside your php script to know if that row is the "particular" one you're searching, then you just select all the columns, or the ones you need.

```
$queryNodeRevision = "SELECT nid, col1, col2 FROM node_revision";

$results = mysqli_query($connection, $queryNodeRevision) or die("Bad Query: $results");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
    if (condiiton) {
        echo "Particular: ".$row['nid']
        ." ".$row['col1']
        ." ".$row['col2'];
    }
}
```

`condition` could be something like `$row['nid'] == 123` for example.

Hope it helps.

Comment: So if I wanted to select all the rows 1 by 1 would I put SELECT * FROM node_revision where $rows;

Comment: `SELECT * from node_revision;` will select all rows and columns and put them in the `$results` object. In your while loop you'll pick a single row each time, do some stuff and echo it. This is very basic stuff. You should read the PHP and MySQL documentation. And in case you need to "get this done" somehow, give more details about exactly what you're trying to achieve.